# apache2 running different version of PHP

Tags: php, apache

I'm running Ubuntu 12.0, apache2.  I manually installed PHP 5.2.17.  I also installed, `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

When I type

`php --version` it shows,

> PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Dec 27 2015 01:01:25)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group

-However when I used the php script

```
<?php
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
echo phpversion('tidy');
?>
```

- it shows that I'm running 
  Current PHP version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21

I have no idea where 5.3.10 came from but is there anything I can do to get Apache to run 5.2.17 instead?  Thank you. 
Ahdee

Comment: This is maybe a duplicate of the thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use 
Don't bother your self with recompilation but focus on the answer of: @Tautologistics

Answer (score 1):

Apache will be loading/using a different binary than the one on your command line.  Comparing the path to the php binary from `phpinfo()` with that found on the command line via `$ which php` will likely show the difference.

To install a specific version of php for mod-php5 there's a handy guide [here](http://www.nicovs.be/install-php-5-2-on-ubuntu-12-04/).  You can also look at compiling a specific version of PHP from source though this becomes slightly more complicated and requires ongoing maintenance to patch.

As this guide suggests, you should really be upgrading to a more recent version. Contrary to the advice of the article (which was accurate at the time of authoring) PHP 5.5 is currently the lowest version still receiving (security only) support.

Ubuntu LTS backports security fixes into its supported php package.  If you opt to use a custom php package that is not in the main repositories (e.g. you stray to a specific version or you decide to compile your preferred version) you'll not be receiving these security patches for your version of PHP which significantly reduces the security of your application.